# Unfriendly NPC keeps sending me a war proposal

Tags: stellaris

A certain empire keeps proposing me to go at war. However I'm not in good terms with said empire (110), and I cant seem to find WHY he keeps asking me. I'm not in the same Alliance, I don't have a defensive pact with him or his allies. Nor do I have those with the person he wants to declare war against (I'm also at bad terms with them).

How can I see why I'm keeping those proposals? Since I have don't have any diplomatic connections with both parties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 1.2.1 any Empire, regardless of diplomatic status (except for actively being at war with you), can invite you to join a war. This even includes a war against yourself, as odd as that may sound.

While the case of asking you to join a war against yourself is probably a bug, the other behavior is not. All you can do is decline any offers.

Comment: and decline, and decline, then decline once more. Repeating the same proposal every few months is what is bothering me the most.